# Вывести список чисел от 1 до 50 в столб

Tags: c#, html

Использую:

```
public static string GoFlig()
{
    List<int> sv = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 50; i++)
    {
        sv.Add(i);
    }
    return string.Join(" ", sv.ToArray());
}
```

вызываю функцию в виде html таблицы)

```
using (StreamWriter vas = new StreamWriter(Log, false, Encoding.UTF8))
{ 

vas.WriteLine("<tr><td style=\"color:#85AB70; width:33.3%; border:2px solid #707070; text-align: center\"><div style=\"height: 31px;line-height: 31px\"><center>{0}</center></p></div></td>", GoFlig());
}
```

Но получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите куда мне занести цикл `for` чтобы он возвращал значения:
В итоге у меня должно получиться так:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   и т.д

**Дополнение**
Результат работы предложенный @Foggy Finder,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код точно такой как написали или вы его упростили?

Comment: Точно такой, я не могу сообразить куда можно занести цикл for и вызвать его пробовал занести в `StringBuilder` так же история.

Comment: Давайте вы просто покажите более полный код. Такой результат просто не мог получится без внешнего цикла.

Comment: Да там используются внешние циклы, но более полный код не покажу, так как очень секретно )) Подскажите просто куда можно по мимо `List<int>` и `StringBuilder` занести цикл `for` ??!

Comment: @Foggy Finder, Если из него можно вынести список то наверное возможно, я сам не знаю, если есть возможность продемонстрируйте?! Может перейдём в Чат?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49296/discussion-between-artes-and-foggy-finder).